# get_query_var( 'paged' ) not working outside of homepage

Tags: wp-query, pagination, paged

Twenty Eleven Theme...

On the home page, I have successfully filtered the loop to display just "Featured" posts with pagination functioning properly through nav links. I'm trying to display posts from all categories on another page called "Unfiltered." Why do the nav links disappear when used on this other page?

edit: if I change the value of 'paged' to '1' or '2', I get the 10 posts that I would expect to so 'paged' seems to work depending on the value I set, just not when I set it to get_query_var( 'paged' )

```
            <?php /* $paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;*/

            $unfiltered_query = new WP_Query ( 

            array (
                'posts_per_page' => 10,
                'paged' =>  get_query_var( 'paged' )
            ) 

        );?>

        <?php if ( $unfiltered_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-above' ); ?>

            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>

                <?php while ( $unfiltered_query->have_posts() ) : $unfiltered_query->the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'excerpt', get_post_format() ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php twentyeleven_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>
```

Comment: Please move your working code to separate answer, usually that is more in line with site's mechanics than editing it in.

Comment: But then it would be buried with unaccepted answers? Hmmm

Comment: There is no rule that only one answer is useful and upvoted. :) You can comment on accepted answer and note that you had added solution to which it led as separate one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`twentyeleven_content_nav()` uses the main query object, `$wp_query`. You'll need to use the `$wp_query` variable, rather than `$unfiltered_query`, then `wp_reset_query()` to restore the original `$wp_query` (which it'll find in `$wp_the_query`, something you should probably avoid touching directly).

As long as you're careful to restore the original query, you're in good shape.

I would submit a patch to core that allows `twentyeleven_content_nav()` to optionally take a query object which it can use for its calculations.

Answer (score 8):

the argument for WP_Query is `paged`, but the query var is `page`, no 'd' on the end.

```
'paged' =>  get_query_var( 'paged' )
```

should be:

```
'paged' =>  get_query_var( 'page' )
```

Comment: Tried that, too. Content navigation still missing. Even tried adding wp_reset_query();

And in case there is any question, I'm using $home_query on the home page.

Comment: I am trying to search the difference between the `paged` and `page` parameter. Can you please provide me some link to resources?

Comment: @RohitPande - see [`WP_Query` pagination parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters). I think both actually work in most circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

What if you replace `get_query_var( 'paged' )` with the global `$paged`? e.g. replace this:

```
$unfiltered_query = new WP_Query ( 

    array (
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'paged' =>  get_query_var( 'paged' )
)
```

...with this:

```
global $paged;

$unfiltered_query = new WP_Query ( 

    array (
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'paged' =>  $paged
)
```

### EDIT

Okay, that apparently won't work. The `$paged` global apparently isn't set until the query is run.

Answer (score 0):

i used simply `wp_Query->paged` directly and it works well, rather than `get_query_var( 'paged' )` witch did not work for me